# click element without affecting other elements with the same structure

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have an HTML element with same structure but I wanted my jquery to affect only the particular element I clicked instead it affects all elements in the DOM. Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kureiii/tnsWj/).

```
//HTML Code
<div class="category">
<h3>This is the title</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Sub menu one</li>
    <li>Sub menu two</li>
    <li>Sub menu three</li>
    <li>Sub menu four</li>
    <li>Sub menu five</li>
    <li>Sub menu six</li>
    <li>Sub menu seven</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="category">
    <h3>This is the title</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Sub menu one</li>
    <li>Sub menu two</li>
    <li>Sub menu three</li>
    <li>Sub menu four</li>
    <li>Sub menu five</li>
    <li>Sub menu six</li>
    <li>Sub menu seven</li>
</ul>
</div>

//jquery

$(function(){
   $('.category > h3').click(function(){
     $('.category > ul').slideToggle("fast");
      });


$('.category > h3').click(function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked')
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $(function(){
   $('.category > h3').click(function(){
     $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
  });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/tnsWj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
   $('.category > h3').click(function(){
     $(this).next("ul").slideToggle("fast");
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tnsWj/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use next function for this, also it is better to combine the two click events for better performance like this

```
$(function(){
 $('.category > h3').click(function(){
   $(this).next("ul").slideToggle("fast");
   $(this).toggleClass('clicked')
 });


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tnsWj/8/

Answer (score 0):

Or like this, may be a little bit less susceptible to changes

```
$(function(){
   $('.category > h3').click(function(){
     $(this).find('.category > ul').slideToggle("fast");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).next('ul').slideToggle("fast");
```

Instead of

```
$('.category > ul').slideToggle("fast");
```